# Remote debugging with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I'm following the instruction at http://bumbu.me/remotely-debug-phantomjs/.

All tutorials say "go to localhost:9000 and there should be a link", however I didn't see the link.

See my screenshoot. Do I miss anything?[image: I didn't see any link.]

Answer (score 0):

Can you see a bullet there, like a bullet from unordeted list? Right-Click at it and inspect it. Inside a list item will be a link. You can copy URL from link's href attribute and open it in another tab.

**Updated**: 
This works on 1.9.x versions of PhantomJS. 
In version 2.0.0 remote debugging is [currently broken](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12864).

If you do need to remotely debug a script and it's not related to Phantom's quirks, I suppose you could temporarily downgrade to [1.9.8 version](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip) just for debugging.

Comment: OK, I did find a link to http://localhost:9000/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=1. The page is empty and develop console says the page is not loaded, Status Code:404 Not OK.